Hitting url of angular application is showing html content of index.html file

Whenever I am hitting the url of my Angular application, I am seeing this html content of index.html instead of rendered page. What can be the reason?

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE10">
  <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>iTime</title>
  <base href="/ItimePreProd/ngiTime/">  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->
</head>

<body>
  
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills.js" defer></script><script src="styles.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.js" defer></script><script src="vendor.js" defer></script><script src="main.js" defer></script></body>


</html>


Do you mean in View Page Source?

Can you be more precise about "content of index.html instead of parsed page"? Do you mean you see the code in the browser instead of rendered html? Is there an error in the console (that would explain why the app doesn't start)?

yes I am seeing html content instead of rendered html

When you inspect the page in developper tools, is the raw code embedded in <pre> or <code> tags? The best way to see what is actually received by the request is to open the developper tools, go to the "network" tab and reload the page, you can see your request and see the raw response there

no code is not embedded in  or  tags

@abhinav its a server configuration problem, check my your html gets rendered as plain text!

actually after login, the page url supposed to come in address bar  should be https://something.com/itimepreprod/ngitime/home but it is coming like https://something.com/ItimePreProd/ngiTime/home#/somepage and it is showing html text instead of rendering index.html. I have checked the routing but it is correct.

@NarenMurali: I am also assuming this but can you help me in this. What can be possible reason or how can i resolve it.

@abhinav its better you edit the question with the tag to the web service you are hosting on,, the web server details are missing, also add the tag for the same!

You should begin by the network tab as I said, check what is sent and received by the browser for your page, don't hesitate to share all relevant parts in the question (obfuscate any sensistive information). For example, the Content-Type of the response should be text/html. If not the case, there may be a server configuration problem

@Kaddath when i am inspecting in element section pre tag is showing like this <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">

Can you confirm your brower is Chrome? Chrome embeds the code in a <pre> tag when the Content-Type is set to text/plain instead of text/html. You should check in developper tools / network tab the content type of the response. If the case, you must fix this on the server and we would need the server details for us to be able to help you

Hi after searching a lot on google I got the solution now my url is working fine.
Problem is resolved after adding rewrite rules in web-config.

It's fine to answer to your own question, however, for it to be useful to others, you should add a little more details, what rewrite rules were necessary and why?
